# Heat and water absorption by calcium chloride

Tags: thermodynamics

Can calcium chloride be effectively used as a desiccant to absorb both heat and moisture?

Comment: ‘absorbing heat’? How does that work?

Answer (score 1):

Anhydrous calcium chloride is an effective desiccant, but the absorption of water by anhydrous calcium chloride is exothermic; i.e. the reaction releases heat.

$$\ce{CaCl2 + 6 H2O -> CaCl2 . 6 H2O}\quad\Delta H = -97\ \mathrm{kJ/mol}$$

Comment: CaCl2 is also deliquescent. It pulls in so much water from the air that eventually you wind up with a concentrated solution of the salt.